# What is the word for making a point by saying nothing?

Tags: single-word-requests

Instead of commenting on what he regarded as a ridiculous proposal he conveyed his disapproval by saying nothing at all.  This is an example of xxxxxx.

Comment: verbum sap is the closest I can think of.

Comment: So he expressed his disapproval by his silence?

Comment: He ***blanked*** the proposal (ignored it, didn't even deign to acknowledge and respond to it).

Comment: He *disregarded* it.

Comment: A pregnant silence, if the speaker breaks off mid-sentence, is called aposiopesis. [if you side with classicists, the stress is prepenultimate; Stephen Fry stresses the first 'o' ].

Comment: In law there's the expression [tacit consent](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/tacit+consent) but it means almost the complete opposite, silence means consensus. In Latin it's *Qui tacet, consentire videtur* (not exactly one word either!)

Comment: @Mari-LouA “Tacit” is great & there’s also [tacit **disapproval**](https://books.google.com/books?id=9dmttO_4gToC&pg=PA223&lpg=PA223&dq=%22tacit+disapproval%22&source=bl&ots=FBXPX4Zf7k&sig=F7XSslyPH8isF8BtVSOxdokG8qg&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiJwJ7J2OHLAhVnsoMKHR-1DW0Q6AEIOTAG#v=onepage&q=%22tacit%20disapproval%22&f=false), which leads to [pocket veto](https://books.google.com/books?id=hNdEAQAAIAAJ&dq=searchwithinvolume&q=%22the+pocket+veto%2C+or+tacit+disapproval%22), which even [appears as 1 word](http://www.wordplays.com/crossword-solver/President's-tacit-disapproval-of-a-bill) in word puzzles.

Comment: (The problem here is that you're not seeing any of the really good responses.)

Comment: So this is like... When you say nothing, and as a result the other person rethinks what they've said and realizes your point?

Answer (score 6):

A single-word answer to fit ‘This is an example of...’ still seems elusive, but I have a couple of brief suggestion and one rather longer one, one of which might suit your purpose.

Depending on the context of your writing, it might be appropriate to say that ***He disdained to answer***.  In fact, Merriam-Webster specifically uses the example ‘disdained to answer their questions’ in [its definition of *disdain*](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/disdain).

With a slightly more judgmental sense, you might also consider ***He scorned to answer***.

(And, on reflection, you *could* truthfully say of his action/conduct, ‘This is an example of disdain/scorn,’ although of a very specific type.  Perhaps it would suit your purposes simply to report the question, followed by ‘his silent disdain’ or ‘his disdainful silence’.)

I’ll mention a longer possibility because it seems suggestive.  It seems to me that the common expression for what you describe is ***He refused [or disdained] to dignify the question with an answer***.  I can't help wondering whether, in a language where that expression is so current, a one-word equivalent might not exist.

Comment: Thank you for all your helpful suggestions - I feel sure that there is a single word for this, but it is so far proving elusive!

Answer (score 4):

This is an example of: silence speaking volumes.

> **silence speaks volumes.**
>
> Silence can mean many things in interpersonal relationships. It's ambiguous. It can express lots of different emotions ranging from joy, happiness, grief, embarrassment to anger, denial, fear, withdrawal of acceptance or love.
>
> [google: silence speaks volumes meaning](https://www.google.com/search?q=His+silence+spoke+volumes&oq=His+silence+spoke+volumes&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i64&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8#q=silence+speaks+volumes+meaning)

Comment: Thank you for this.  I have an idea though that there is a single word for conveying this.

Comment: This is another answer I'm not sure whether to upvote or downvote.

Comment: I can't prove there isn't one. I can only offer an idiom that shows it's unlikely that there is one.

Comment: Judging by the negative reception given so far to both of your two good multi-word answers (+1 each),  it seems like the single-word tag is being taken seriously/literally today, so after thanking you for so bravely testing the waters and running interference for the rest of us I’ll just leave the two thoughts that came to my mind as possible distant also-rans after your two (pregnant pause/pregnant silence) here with a cc to @PennyRoss .

Answer (score 2):

**stonewalling** (noun):

an act of delaying or obstructing a person, request or process

to **stonewall** (verb):

delay or obstruct (a request, process or person) by refusing to answer questions or by being evasive

> *'When she confronted Don, he stonewalled her and limited her access to the business records.'*
>
> *'she has also stonewalled queries about her love life'*

Source: [ODO](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/stonewall)

[Merriam Webster's Dictionary of Allusions](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=ACB81ZeNN5sC&pg=PA519&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q&f=false) details the etymology of *'stonewall'* in US politics.

Comment: Yes but one can stonewall (refuse to answer questions) or be evasive loudly, so it has little to do with innate silence.

Comment: @AlanCarmack yes, but because it can be a 'noisy' silence, doesn't negate the fact it also applies to a 'silent' silence. 'Innate' silence is not what is required here.

Answer (score 1):

To the extent that [*Wiktionary*’s entry for “**dismissiveness**"](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/dismissiveness) includes the notion of “**passively** showing indifference or disregard” (as well as that of “actively dismissing or rejecting ideas or evidence"), you could interpret “passively” to mean/include “silently” or “by/with silence” and perhaps use that single word to say that:
 “This is an example of **dismissiveness**.”

Personally, however, I would stretch it to two words to clarify that the disregard/disapproval was shown by/with silence alone (i.e., not accompanied with a dismissive facial/hand/eye-rolling gesture) and say that:
 “This is an example of [**dismissive silence**](https://books.google.com/books?id=a4jnUr-5SBIC&pg=PA114&lpg=PA114&dq=%22dismissive+silence%22&source=bl&ots=h4oYJ83Y8q&sig=Pzja809xM6VTVWgw-ggGvZ2-Mu4&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj496aUuuPLAhVFJx4KHegWCLMQ6AEIPjAI#v=onepage&q=%22dismissive%20silence%22&f=false).”

(example use of “dismissive silence” from ‘The Poetics of Consent: Collective Decision Making and the Iliad’ by David F. Elmer, via ‘Google Books’)

(for three more examples of “dismissive silence,” please see pages 16 and 20 of Patricia Olivia Covarrubias’ article  ‘Masked Silence Sequences: Hearing
Discrimination in the College Classroom’ found on the University of New Mexico/Dept. of Communication and Journalism’s website [here](https://cjdept.unm.edu/research/recent/docs/covarrubias_masked_silence_sequences_2008.pdf).

Answer (score 0):

In politics, when the president does this it's called a

> **pocket veto**
>
> A pocket veto is a legislative maneuver that allows a president or other official with veto power to exercise that power over a bill by taking no action (instead of affirmatively vetoing it).
>
> [google: pocket veto](https://www.google.com/search?q=Pocket+veto&oq=Pocket+veto&aqs=chrome..69i57&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)

Answer (score 0):

***[speech is silver, (but)] silence is golden***

> (*saying*) Said to ​mean it is often ​better to say nothing
>
> [Cambridge Advanced Learner's Dictionary](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/fr/dictionnaire/anglais/silence-is-golden)
>
> Speaking is good but saying nothing is better. [**Discretion can be worth more than even eloquent words**](https://en.m.wikiquote.org/wiki/Silence).
>
> [UsingEnglish](https://www.englishclub.com/ref/esl/Sayings/Talking/Speech_is_silver_silence_is_golden_940.htm)

***Some things are better left unsaid***

> better left unsaid
>
> [refers to a topic that] should not be discussed; [refers to a thought that] everyone is thinking, but would cause difficulty if talked about in public. (A typical beginning for this phrase might be It is, That is, The details are, or even Some things are. See the examples.) Mary: *I really don't know how to tell you this.* Bob: *Then don't. Maybe it's better left unsaid.* Bill: *I had such a terrible fight with Sally last night. I can't believe what I said.* Bob: *I don't need to hear all about it. Some things are better left unsaid.*
>
> [McGraw-Hill Dictionary of American Idioms and Phrasal Verbs](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/better+left+unsaid)

***silence is the best policy***

> [A Dictionary of American Proverbs](https://books.google.fr/books?id=AbJ1tVGmiTgC&pg=RA2-PA722&dq=%22silence+is+the+best+policy%22&hl=fr&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiH0POyj-TLAhVMvBoKHUaZD8cQ6AEIIzAA#v=onepage&q=%22silence%20is%20the%20best%20policy%22&f=false)

Answer (score 0):

Someone might convey their disapproval of someone else's proposal, which they regard as ridiculous, by **meeting it with a blank stare**, that is by not saying anything, by letting their silence be comment enough. *A blank stare* can be *due to lack of feeling, understanding, or interest*.

*someone can meet something with a blank stare*

*something can be met by a blank stare*

(Why not 'with'? Isn't the 'blank stare' the instrument rather than the agent? But that's another question…)

Example sentence from the *Longman Dictionary of Contemporary English*:

> *His pleas were met by a **blank stare*** (= a stare with no expression, understanding, or interest).

I didn't know *blank* could be used as a verb, but FumbleFingers does use it this way in his comment to the question, so there is your single-word expression!